# Search, insert, and replace the previous line of a text in Python

Tags: python

I have a text file with the following information(example)

```
a = text1 text2 text3 text4  
b = text1 text8 text9 text5 
c = text6 text5 text1 text9   
d = text5 text4 text2 text9
```

and so on...

What I would like to do is to find a combination, for example, **text8 text9** replace it with text10 and create a new sentence next to it. The final result will be something like:

```
a = text1 text2 text3 text4
b = text1 text8 text9 text5
b1 = text1 text10 text5
c = text6 text5 text1 text9
d = text5 text4 text2 text9
```

So far I have done something like this (I am new to python):

```
import re

text = open('file.txt').read()
match_found=False
matches = re.finditer('text2', text)
m = None
for m in matches:
    match_found = True
    pass
if (match_found):
    m.start()
    m.end()
text[1:m.end()] + "text10" + text[(m.end()+1):]
```

but nothing happens and also, that line can appear in other sentences like:

```
a = text1 text2 text3 text4
b = text1 text8 text9 text5
b1 = text1 text10 text5
c = text6 text5 text1 text9
d = text5 text4 text8 text9
d1 = text5 text4 text10
```

Comment: How would you determine the number of the new 'sentence' (`b1`)? Simple integer increment? Can you have more than one `b` 'sentence'?

Comment: You need to fix your indentation to make your program legal to execute.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. Minimal, complete, verifiable example applies here.

Comment: What if multiple "text8 text9" happens in the same line? Do you insert `b1`, `b2`, etc? Or are you just interested in the first occurance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory is not an issue, a search & replace procedure is relatively simple:

```
search = "text8 text9"
replace = "text10"

with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = []  # storage list for (modified) lines
    for line in f:  # read the file line by line
        lines.append(line)  # add the current line to the lines list
        index = line.find(search)  # attempt to find the index of the search string
        if index != -1:  # search string found in the current line
            equals_index = line.find("=")  # find where the equals sign is
            name = line[:equals_index].strip() + "1"  # create a new 'sentence' name
            # replace the found string with the 'replace' string
            value = line[equals_index+1:index] + replace + line[index + len(search):]
            lines.append("{} ={}".format(name, value))  # add the new sentence
    # let's write down the updates, you can omit the following if you don't want to
    # update the file and use the `lines` list for whatever further manipulation
    f.seek(0)  # rewind back to the beginning of the file
    f.writelines(lines)  # write down the lines
    f.truncate()  # truncate the rest in case the new content is smaller than the old
```

If memory is an issue, instead of storing the lines open another file stream to a temporary file and write to it directly instead of appending to the `lines` list, then in the end just overwrite your `file.txt` with that temporary file. Of course, you don't need to change the file at all, or you can store the lines to an another file.

This, however, doesn't properly handle the case of having multiple 'sentences' like:

```
a = text1 text2 text3 text4
b = text1 text8 text9 text5
b = text1 text8 text9 text5
c = text6 text5 text1 text9
```

Or if there are multiple matches in a line, i.e. `b = text1 text8 text9 text5 text8 text9`. You'll have to clarify what should happen in such cases (and if they can even occur). This also assumes that there are no blank lines between your 'sentences' - if there are, make sure that you add extra lines when building your new sentence on mach (i.e. `lines.append("\n{} ={}\n".format(name, value))`). Also, you might have to tweak line ending to `\r\n` if your file is in a Windows 'format'...

You'll have to describe such edge cases if you want us to address them, tho.

Answer (score 1):

We can store all the files lines in some list `inlines` and then loop over each line and find and replace `'text8 text9'` with `'text10'` and then store the old line and the new line in a new list `outlines` to be used however you want later on.

Assumption due to question ambiguity: We use the 3rd argument of `str.replace` to only replace the first occurrence of the string.

```
inlines = [line for line in open('in.txt', 'r')]
outlines = []
for line in inlines:
    label = line.split(' ')[0]
    newline = line.replace('text8 text9', 'text10', 1).replace(label, f'{label}1', 1)
    outlines.append(line)
    outlines.append(newline)

    # To print the lines as well we can add this
    print(line)
    print(newline)
```

Comment: This repeats every line, only changing text8 text9 if it's there, and not updating the label before the equal sign

Comment: This isn't a very good idea when you can have occurrences within each other. For example, if we want to search for "a a" and replace with "b", and the line is "a a a a" there is actually three occurrences that are overlapped. Your method `replace("a a", "b")` returns "b b", and not "b a a", "a b a", and "a a b". This also emphasizes that the question requirements are vague.

Comment: @darksky yes I noticed that but realize that it's very ambiguous as to which option we'd want to output.

Comment: @Pedro thanks for the heads up, I missed that requirement and fill fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
import re

old = 'text8 text9'
new = 'text10'

text = open('file.txt').read()

new_lines = []
for line in text.split('\n'):
  # Replace all matches in one line in one go
  new_line = line.replace(old, new)
  new_lines.append(line)

  # There is a match; increment number
  if new_line != line:

    # Get number before equals sign
    parts = new_line.split(' =', 1)
    old_number = re.search(r'\d+', parts[0])
    new_number = 1

    # If there is a number, increment
    if old_number:
      old_number = int(old_number.group(0))
      new_number = old_number + 1
      parts[0] = parts[0].replace(str(old_number), str(new_number))

    # If there is no number, concatenate 1
    else:
      parts[0] += '1'
    
    new_lines.append(parts[0] + ' =' + parts[1])
    
print '\n'.join(new_lines)
```

This does not print multiple lines for multiple matches though. Given an input:

> a = text1 text2 text3 text4
>
> b = text1 text8 text9 text5
>
> c = text6 text5 text1 text9
>
> d20 = text5 text4 text2 text8 text9
>
> e60 = text5 text4 text2 text8 text9 text8 text9

This will generate the output:

> a = text1 text2 text3 text4
>
> b = text1 text8 text9 text5
>
> b1 = text1 text10 text5
>
> c = text6 text5 text1 text9
>
> d20 = text5 text4 text2 text8 text9
>
> d21 = text5 text4 text2 text10
>
> e60 = text5 text4 text2 text8 text9 text8 text9
>
> e61 = text5 text4 text2 text10 text10

You can run this example here:

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/JZ84/0.js"></script>
```

or edit it [here](https://repl.it/JZ84).